# How to use log4j2 Commons Logging Bridge

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-commons, log4j2

I want to use log4j2 Commons Logging Bridge with commons 1.2. I tried to use something like follows:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl;

public class MyClass{

    private static Log log = LogFactoryImpl.getLog(DropinsBundleDeployer.class);
         .
         .
         .
    log.error("Error occured", e);
}
```

But when I'm running the code I'm getting following issue and cannot see any log:

```
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

However the log4j2.xml file is in the class path.
How can I correctly use commons logging 1.2 with log4j2 ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may want to look at the FAQ page on [which jars you need](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#which_jars).

You will need the following jars on the classpath:

- log4j-api-2.2
- log4j-core-2.2
- log4j-jcl-2.2
- commons logging

Also please ensure that log4j-1.2 is **not** in your classpath. That error messages looks like a log4j-1.2 error...

Comment: If I use log4j-jcl-2.2 still do I need to have commons logging jar ? or using jcl bridge alone is enough ?

Comment: You need both the commons-logging jar and the log4j-jcl bridge jar.

Comment: @RemkoPopma Thank you for the answer. Been searching and searching and searching....for why a library that uses Commons Logging stopped outputting log data when we upgraded to Log4jv2.