# Log4j Commons Logging Bridge ignored

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, apache-commons-logging

Our web app runs in a tomcat 9 container and uses **Log4j** 2.13.3 as logging system.

The web app includes org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop 2.3, which uses apache **commons-logging** (version 1.2 in our setup instead of 1.0.4 originally used in fop).

This combination has been running for years using log4-jcl, the Commons Logging Bridge, and all commons-logging output correctly went into the files configured by log4j. The configuration is fairly easy, as described [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29838406/578759)

However, for no apparent reason, fop has recently started writing all its (rather verbose) logs to stderr (i.e. directly to catalina.out) instead of the log file configured, but only on **some** of our systems. We have some 50 tomcat instances running basically identical software and identical system configurations; one third of them still logs correctly.

I assume that commons-logging doesn't find log4j-jcl's implementation of org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.

Debugging log4j using *Configuration status="trace"* doesn't provide any hint of a failure in log4j-jcl or elsewhere.

I'm out of my wits. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can set the system property `org.apache.commons.logging.diagnostics.dest` to `STDERR`, `STDOUT` or the path to a file, in order to enable JCL's diagnostic logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question in case it's helpful to others.

I needed to add a file called **commons-logging.properties** in the classpath, containing one line:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory=org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl
```

Kudos to Piotr for his comment about setting org.apache.commons.logging.diagnostics.dest.

Apparently, if the class is not explicitly specified, the implementation of LogFactory that is actually used depends on the (somewhat random) order the classloader loads the potential candidates.

I my webapp a maven dependency brought sl4f along as a transitive dependency, so on some systems slf4j was chosen instead of log4j, but slf4 didn't have a valid configuration and defaulted to STDERR.

Answer (score 2):

While your answer explains why Log4j 2.x is not chosen as JCL's backend, some details don't add up: the original `commons-logging` **never** chooses SLF4j as backend (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/commons-logging/blob/5660a6f6ec7800136027cd4fc594d014e43678a0/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl.java#L789)). Hence the situation must be more complicated:

- The original `commons-logging` discovers alternative [`LogFactory`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.html) implementations through the `ServiceLoader` utility.
- You must have two alternative `LogFactory` implementations in your classpath: [`log4j-jcl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-jcl) and [`spring-jcl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jcl). The latter is a **complete** replacement for the standard `commons-logging` library (i.e. it contains a copy of `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` itself) and has some complex backend selection rules (cf. [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/17cdd97c375579e024424b7eefc5b8a83278bfcd/spring-jcl/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/LogAdapter.java#L50)), which in your case prefer SLF4J over Log4j 2.x.

Since the classloader randomly loads the `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` class from either `commons-logging` or `spring-jcl` you can have two kinds of problems:

1. if the `commons-logging` version is chosen the `ServiceLoader` randomly loads `log4j-jcl`'s implementation or `spring-jcl`'s implementation. You already solved this case in your answer.
2. if the `spring-jcl`'s version is chosen the SLF4J backend will be used.

To solve all these potential problems I would:

1. Remove the original `commons-logging` and keep the clone `spring-jcl`. Even better I would exclude both and use the deterministic [`jcl-over-slf4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.32) (complete JCL replacement that always uses SLF4J)
2. Remove `log4j-jcl` since it is no longer needed (it is only required by the original `commons-logging`),
3. Add the [`log4j-slf4j-impl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl) SLF4J binding.

This solution adds an additional API to your logging configuration (JCL -> SLF4J -> Log4j 2.x), but guarantees stability. It is also the way [`spring-boot-starter-log4j2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2) works.

Comment: If it incorporated the detail from Hok's own answer, this should be the accepted answer. This is exactly the configuration I ended up using when incorporating SLF4J into our Spring log4j & Commons Logging project, then upgraded the whole thing from log4j 1.x to 2.x. It would've been an easier process if I had seen this answer then haha